# How to modify headings in conditionalPanel in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

I created a dashboard in Shiny R on which a text should only be displayed under certain conditions which are defined in my server class:

```
output$is_old_data <- reactive(
    if(get_most_recent_date2(dshb_qt_2, input$radio)){
      1
    }else{
      0
    }
  )
  outputOptions(output, "is_old_data", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

In the UI I created the following:

```
h5(
                  conditionalPanel("output.is_old_data == 1", h5("Os dados apresentados infra dizem respeito ao calculo efectuado
                                                                 para a ultima data de referencia com dados disponiveis. Assim que 
                                                                 possivel a informacao sera actualizada para o mes seleccionado."))
                ),
```

However, I would like to make the text bold and change the color. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `tags$b()` for bold and `style="color: blue;"` (or any other color).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h5(
        tags$b("Os dados apresentados infra dizem respeito ao calculo efectuado
                para a ultima data de referencia com dados disponiveis. Assim que 
                possivel a informacao sera actualizada para o mes seleccionado.", 
               style="color: blue;")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great, please accept the answer so that others know it's answered.